# Efficient way of marking duplicates (except first) based on a subset of columns in BigQuery

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery, etl

So I have a dataset which looks like:

| user_ID | order_ID | order_start_date | is_returning? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 23-Mar-2021 | 0 |
| 2 | 1235 | 23-Mar-2021 | 0 |
| 2 | 1236 | 23-Mar-2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 1237 | 24-Mar-2021 | 1 |
| 3 | 1238 | 28-Mar-2021 | 0 |

Except for the `is_returning` column and I want that to be calculated based on if that user_ID is seen before or not.

In pandas, its an easy one-liner as:

```
all_data['is_returning'] = all_data.user_id.duplicated().astype(int)
```

But in BQ, I am yet to find a straightforward way of doing so. As of now, I have got till

```
(SELECT COUNT(USER_ID) AS num_users_with_2_orders FROM
 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_NUMBER) AS ORDERS, USER_ID FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table` WHERE
    order_number IN (SELECT DISTINCT ORDER_NUMBER FROM (SELECT order_number, sum(usd_total_price) as totals
         FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table`
         GROUP BY order_number
         HAVING totals <= @maximum_value AND totals >= @minimum_value))
   AND USER_ID IN
   (SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID
     FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table` WHERE
     USER_ID <> -1 AND
     
     CAST(order_start_date AS DATE) >= PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE) AND CAST(order_start_date AS DATE) <= PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE))

      
 GROUP BY USER_ID
 HAVING ORDERS >= 2))
```

Then I use these user_IDs to compare. If they are in original table, I say its returning. While being overly complex, it doesn't serve the purpose of `keep = 'first'` argument as it marks all orders not excluding the first one. For that I have to apply an additional condition of `order_start_date <> MIN(ORDER_START_DATE)` grouped by `user_ID`.

So my question is: **What would be a more efficient method of achieving the same?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BigQuery this can be achieved with analytic functions like [row_number](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#numbering_function_concepts):

```
with my_table as (
  select 1 as user_id, 1234 as order_id union all
  select 2, 1235 union all
  select 2, 1236 union all
  select 1, 1237 union all
  select 3, 1238
)
select 
  user_id,
  order_id,
  IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY order_id) > 1, 1, 0) AS is_returning
from my_table
order by order_id
```

[image]